# what is best IDE for autocomplete helper in cake framework

Tags: cakephp, ide, autocomplete, helper

what is best IDE for auto-complete helper .
because i can not remember all method or property of html helper or another
for example :

```
$this->Html->tableHeaders(array('Date','Title','Active'));
```

but i should write tableHeaders and IDE not recognize Html's property and methods.

thanks.

Comment: SubLimeText 2 offers very good option for CakePHP.

Comment: Whoever nominated this for reopening, how about leaving a comment explaining on what basis? The "not constructive" close reason no longer exists, but as far as I can tell it's off-topic on the grounds that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always been a fan of using Eclipse+PDT with Cake, as it supports completion quite well.

See: [Code Completion for CakePHP in Eclipse](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/code-completion-for-cakephp-in-eclipse)

It's also worth noting that at least one of the main developers of CakePHP uses Eclipse (I know this because he wrote the above-linked article).

Answer (score 1):

you should not only select IDEs because of their autocomplete functionality.

I only know PHPDesigner which handles it pretty well.
All IDEs need a file where the specific rules for the framework can be found, though.
Otherwise they would not know how to autocomplete some classes.

Comment: seriously? unaccept after 3 months?